# Flow dynamically adding a property to Error

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I try to add custom properties to the native JavaScript `Error`

```
  const error = new Error(message);
  error.name = name;
  error.request = request;
```

Flow throws the following error (which is expected):

```
16:   error.request = request;
             ^^^^^^^^ property `request`. Property not found in
16:   error.request = request;
       ^^^^^ Error
```

Can I create an interface for this?
If yes, how to "downcast" the `Error` to the new interface?

I've read a lot of articles with similar scenarios, but it seems like the solution is either:
- obvious and it is hard to find for newcomers
- or not existing, so we should use another pattern

Any example here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Extend the object and add your own properties

Comment: There is a lot of reasons for which I do not want to extend the object.
Here is what I'm more trying to achieve: http://gunargessner.com/subclassing-exception/
But Flow doesn't like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like in most languages, your best bet might be to extend the Error object with your extra properities..

eg. something like ->

```
class MyError extends Error {
  name: string;
  request: any;
  constructor(message, name, request) {
    super (message);
    this.name = name;
    this.request = request;
  }
}
```

And then use like ->

```
const error = new MyError(message, name, request);
```

Alternatively if sub-classing is not an option.  Maybe ->

```
const error = (new Error(message):any);
error.name = name;
error.request = request;
```

Or with a bit more type-checking.

```
interface ErrorNameRequest {
   name?: string;
   request?: any;
}

const error = (new Error(message):ErrorNameRequest);
error.name = 'one two three';
error.name2 = 'xyz';  //error..
```

Comment: This would indeed solve the issue, but would introduce new ones.
I'm more trying to find a way to keep my code but have Flow accept it.

Comment: Not sure of the down-vote, but I've updated my answer with some more alternatives.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I ended up using a mix of both last suggestions: `const error: CrawlError = (new Error(message): any);`.